# export table from mysql to csv following fields properties

Tags: mysql, csv

suppose I have a table in mysql with the following fields:

```
 id int auto_increment,
 name varchar(50),
 role enum('M','I','E')
```

Is there a way where I can export these data to csv but following the field properties, meaning that I wouldn't be able to add fields or rows to the csv table unless they follow these properties (id being auto-incremented, and role being one of the three option M, I and E).

Comment: It is up to the software that edits files to enforce such constraints; the file itself has no control over its content.  Your question is analogous to asking whether a piece of paper can enforce that it be written upon only with red ink.

Comment: then is it possible to export a mysql table into microsoft access ?

Comment: Yes. One way (of many) would be via [the ODBC connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html#connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-import).  But why do you want to do this?

Comment: to csv, because it's easier to enter data by any user.
To access, you're right it's not a good idea